# How can I make CorePlot work with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I read the tutorial on how to use core plot (http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)
The project I am working on is written in swift.

I did everything to import the CorePlot library.
To make sure I did it right, I created a new objective C file and called

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

it worked in the test objective-c file (built without errors)

I then put the import statement in the bridging header file, and got 27 errors ALL saying '... the current deployment target does not support automated __weak'

From this post ([CorePlot in Swift can not call “numberForPlot”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806059/coreplot-in-swift-can-not-call-numberforplot)), 
I know I can make core plot work in my swift project somehow.

Can anyone recommend something ?

Thank you for helping.

I followed these steps to import the library :

Static Library Install
You can also just copy the Core Plot library directly into your project in binary form.

1. Copy the CorePlotHeaders directory to your Xcode project
2. Copy the Core Plot library to your Xcode project.
3. Open your apps Target Build Settings, and for Other Linker Flags include this:

-ObjC
(-all_load used to be required as a linker flag, but this is no longer needed in Xcode 4.2)

4. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.
5. Add the Accelerate framework to the project (release 2.0 and later).
6. Change your C/C++ Compiler in the project build settings to LLVM GCC 4.2 or LLVM 1.6.

Comment: There was an update concerning Swift/CorePlot just yesterday. Looks like the only graph you can currently do with Swift is a pie chart.  See here: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96

Comment: @kmn Check this blog post : http://blog.alwold.com/2014/09/03/coreplot-nsdecimal-and-swift/ it has 2 parts . Check if you get any solution for ur issue. I don't have much knowledge of core plot but find swift integration of this in this blog. Check this it may help you.

Comment: I'm using CorePlot with CocoaPods and it seems to be working fine in my Swift project. Have you tried that?